# connect-history-api-fallback get cannot access

Tags: express

During setup of nodejs(as backend, port: 3333), and vuejs(frontend, port: 8080) environment, I was unable to access 'GET /article'. Also, when I remove connect-history-api-fallback, all I can see is json formatted database data.

How can I fix this?

Below is the code for app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

app.use(history({
  index: '/index.html',
  verbose: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// app.use(bodyParser.json());

var IndexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var ArticleRouter = require('./routes/article');

app.use('/', IndexRouter);
app.use('/article', ArticleRouter);
```

Below is the code for routes/article.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('article get 접근하였습니다.');
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            throw error;
        }
        const sqlQuery = 'SELECT * from board_article';
        connection.query(sqlQuery, function (err, rows) {

            if (err) {
                connection.release();
                throw error;
            } else {
                res.json(rows);
                connection.release();
            }
        });
    });
});
```